# expanding links in the tweets in twitter using twitter 4j

Tags: java, mysql, twitter, twitter4j

Hey i am doing a project of data retrieval from tweets from twitter, i am collecting tweets from certain kinds of events, few of the post contains some links, few are expanded and few are shorten, i want to save link from each tweets to my mysql database. I have found code for expanding url, someone please tell me will this work for every shorten url.

```html
for (URLEntity urle : status.getURLEntities()) {
 System.out.println(urle.getDisplayURL());
 System.out.println(urle.getExpandedURL());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With that code you will print the url twice, from the [Javadoc](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/URLEntity.html#getExpandedURL--)

> **getDisplayURL**
>   
>   Returns: the display URL if mentioned URL is shorten, or null if no shorten URL was mentioned.

So, for every URLEntity you will need to print the expanded URL if it's shortened

```
for (URLEntity urle : status.getURLEntities()) {
    if(urle.getExpandedURL()){System.out.println(urle.getExpandedURL());}
    else {System.out.println(urle.getDisplayURL());}
}
```

Or in you case, save them to a database.